# How to set Xamarin Android ForegroundColorSpan.ForegroundColor Property at runtime?

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, spannable

The Xamarin Android ForegroundColorSpan.ForegroundColor Property is readonly.

How can we then set this at runtime if we want to dynamically change the color of a span?

**UPDATED**

To provide more information, I'm trying to recreate the example given in Android documentation. The below code is in Java, but due to the read only nature of the span's color property in Xamarin Android, how can this code be recreated in Xamarin?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BulletPointSpan bulletSpan = new BulletPointSpan(Color.RED);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString("Text is spantastic");
        // setting the span to the bulletSpan field
        spannable.setSpan(bulletSpan, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        styledText.setText(spannable);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // change the color of our mutable span
                bulletSpan.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                // color won’t be changed until invalidate is called
                styledText.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a snippet of code that reveals the problem. Perhaps show the declaration that includes the span, then show the (failed) line of code that attempts to set it. This will make it easier for others to give help that is relevant to your exact situation. [Sometimes the workaround is different depending on your exact code.] And will be more useful to others in the future with a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. Please see my updates above.

Comment: Please show your attempt at Xamarin.Android code. I understand that it won't compile, but that will make it easier to help - people can see the exact xamarin code. Anyway, given that `BulletPointSpan` is not a built-in Android class, that doc example is based on source code somewhere. If you track that down, you can translate it into c#. Perhaps you are trying to use `BulletSpan` instead. You are right that doesn't have a color setter. Regardless of whether working in java or c#. If you use that class, you'll have to create a new `bulletSpan` with the desired color.

Comment: Hi Steve, this code came directly from Android documentation. I have provided the link above. It is not exactly what my problem is, but it is analogous. Please help to assume the BulletSpan is my ForegroundColorSpan. What the Android documentation is trying to say is that the span's attributes can be changed even after the spannable has been assigned to the TextView. With that in mind, I think the problem I'm facing should be quite clear. It is: how can I call setColor on an object that has no setter implemented. If it is not possible, does that mean Android's documentation is incorrect?

Comment: I understand. The Android doc says that `BulletPointSpan`s color can be changed later. Nothing incorrect about that, BUT you are using a different class which lacks the setter. There is no way to change `BulletSpan`'s color after the fact. *"You'll have to create a new `bulletSpan` with the desired color."* If you can't figure out how that helps you, then please **add to the question** whatever **Xamarin.Android** code you have written, including the line that won't compile (because no setter). Then I or someone else can show you what to do.

Comment: ... show where you declare a `BulletSpan` (`... = new BulletSpan...`?), and what you add it to (`spannable.SetSpan(bulletSpan, ...`?). Plus the method where you attempt to change its color (but can't, because there is no setter). The fix will be something like `spannable.SetSpan(new BulletSpan(...new color...);`.

Comment: I think your second comment above solves my problem. I reread the Android docs again and they say you need to derive from the Android span class and create your own custom class. Then in the custom class, override the updateDrawState method where you can then change the color as you desire. Will give this a shot and report back on how that goes, with code if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: `_span.SetColor(cb.Color);` ---> This didn't work. But what I did do was add the span back into the spannable, and this is a good enough work around for me for now: `_spannable.SetSpan(_span, _spannable.GetSpanStart(_span),                             _spannable.GetSpanEnd(_span), SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);`

Comment: That's basically what I said in my last comment: You can't `SetColor`, so instead do `SetSpan` again. Anyway, now that you have it working, please add `Your Answer` below, showing the code snippet that worked. That will help people in the future (who might not read through all these comments!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply again, but, correct me if I'm wrong, does the fact that `_span.SetColor(cb.Color)` still doesn't work suggests that there is still a bug in the underlying .NET code? Does a work around still constitute a proper answer to the problem?

Comment: No. See my very first comment. `SetColor` **is not a concept** in the **built-in** `Span` classes. In the example that you were looking at, if you follow link to source code, `BulletPointSpan` is a class that was **defined as part of that sample.** It has a `SetColor` - which does this technique for you. This has misled you to expect to be able to do that to other Span classes. You *could* do something similar to that sample: **define your own subclass** of `BulletSpan`, and add such a method, and then use *your* new subclass instead of using BulletSpan directly.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but the difference here is that I've implemented an **override** method on my custom span:   `public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint)
  {
   base.UpdateDrawState(textPaint);
   textPaint.Color = Color;

  }`
which should allow my custom code to be called by the parent class and therefore should affect the visual display of the span in real-time fashion, or at least when I call Invalidate(). This behaviour is described in the Android documentation on spans that I reference in my link above.

Comment: Here's what I think happened: You saw a SetColor on one type of span, `BulletPointSpan`. You've got it into your head that you should be able to call SetColor on a different type, `BulletSpan`. Read the API page for [BulletSpan class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.text.style.bulletspan?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12). Is there a SetColor method? No. Not a bug - just not a feature that exists. Everything else is not relevant. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can see the source of `BulletPointSpan` - its in a link on the example you quote. In there, is a definition of `SetColor`. If you want, you could define `public class MyBulletSpan : BulletSpan{ public void SetColor(...) { ... } }`. Then you would have your own class, `MyBulletSpan`, that understands how to do SetColor. Use `MyBulletSpan` in xaml and code, wherever you now have `BulletSpan`. *Then* SetColor would work. Pretty cool, yes?

Comment: Until you define `SetColor`, it doesn't help that you have overridden `UpdateDrawState`. The class still doesn't understand the method name `SetColor`.